# spring mvc decoding + is being replaced with space

Tags: iphone, rest, spring-mvc

I have problem in Spring MVC pattern. When i call the web service form iPhone app with encoded value, The decoding is not happening properly. Not sure about what the issue is.
the + sign is getting replaced with a space " ".
Below is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><br>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"<br>
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"<br>
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"<br>
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"><br>
<display-name>APPLICATIONNAME</display-name><br>
<filter><br>
<filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name><br>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEnco dingFilter</filter-class><br>
<init-param><br>
<param-name>encoding</param-name><br>
<param-value>UTF-8</param-value><br>
</init-param><br>
<init-param><br>
<param-name>forceEncoding</param-name><br>
<param-value>true</param-value><br>
</init-param><br>
</filter><br>
<filter-mapping><br>
<filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name><br>
<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern><br>
</filter-mapping><br>
<servlet><br>
<servlet-name>spring</servlet-name><br>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherSe rvlet</servlet-class><br>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup><br>
</servlet><br>
<servlet-mapping><br>
<servlet-name>spring</servlet-name><br>
<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern><br>
</servlet-mapping><br>
<welcome-file-list><br>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file><br>
</welcome-file-list><br>
</web-app><br>
```

My controller class

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

@Autowired
private LoginServiceImpl loginService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/getUserDetails", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
LoginData getUserDetails(@ModelAttribute LoginDetails loginDetails) {
LOGGER.debug("Session ID = " + loginDetails.getSessionID());
}
```

Sample input request from iPhone APP

```
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *urlString = @"http://localhost:8080/rest/getUserDetails";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLConnection *connection= [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest
                                                             delegate:self];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sessionID=%@",@"ABCD+/EFGH"];
NSData *a=[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"encoded %@",a);
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:a];
    [connection start];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@" %@ ",returnString);
NSLog(@"%@",error);
```

On the server side instead of "ABCD+/EFGH" i am getting "ABCD /EFGH". SO the plus (+) is not getting decoded. 
What needs to be done to get the plus (+) on the server? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's an expected behavour.

In [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type) (used for sending form data in POST) space is encoded as `+`, and real `+` should be represented in percent-encoded form (`%2B`).

I think it would be better to use some kind of built-in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding routine, if available on iPhone, instead of manual replacement.

Comment: Yes, it solved the problem. Thanks a lot. But i would like to know which all characters will have this problem?

Comment: I am not having any issue in sending = and / (Equal symbol and front slash)